# unistall virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, deb

I installed virtual box with

`virtualbox-5.0_5.0.12-104815-Ubuntu-precise_amd64.deb`

but because of some issues I tried to delete it.
First I deleted all the folders of virtualbox situated in `/usr/bin/othe-folders`. But if I clicked on `virtualbox-5.0_5.0.12-104815-Ubuntu-precise_amd64.deb` the USC shown me the `reinstall` button.

Then I tried

`sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.12-104815-Ubuntu-precise_amd64.deb`

but terminal shown  this message: [image]

So with `ps aux | grep virtualbox`

I found the process. 
But if I try to kill the process I get:

```
bash: kill: (8368) - No such process
```

The the strange thing is that every time I run `ps aux | grep virtualbox` the process ID changes. How can I solve?

Comment: **Do not** manually delete anything you've installed using dpkg unless you know what you're doing. And it's obvious you don't. Use `apt-get remove packagename` to do so. To stop virtualbox try `sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox stop` or `sudo service virtualbox stop`

Comment: I tried with `apt-get`, but I got `Package virtualbox is not installed, so not removed`, why I can't us `dpkg`? I know that to delete .deb I have to use it.With the command for stop the process I get  `not found` errors.thanks

Comment: Maybe the package name is not `virtualbox` but `virtualbox-5.0` or something else? Do a `dpkg -l | grep -i virtualbox` - it will show you a list of packages with `virtualbox` in theirs names. Those with `ii` in the first column are installed.

Comment: you were right. the package is virtualbox-5.0. But if I try to unistall it, I still get the same error (VB is running..)

Comment: Try to stop it using commands which I gave you in the previous comments.

Comment: with the first I get `command not  found  `, while with the second  i get `unrecognized service '. what about reinstalling  the package  from the .deb file and then  unistall?

Comment: Yes, first I would try to reinstall the package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34615/discussion-between-linofex-and-nsilent22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution that worked:
1. Install midnight commander (`sudo apt-get install mc`)
2. Run it as root and navigate to the directory the package lies.
3. Enter the package (by taping [enter]), enter the directory CONTENTS and copy all the directories that have been removed manually back to theirs place.
4. Reinstall the package (just to be sure everything is 'by the book').
5. Remove the package using `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have left the virtualbox package in a half-installed/half-uninstalled state. Manually deleting packages you have installed using a package manager is very bad and most often lead to scenarios like this one.

To proceed you have to find all installed virtualbox-packages using `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`. Now purge each package with `dpkg -P ...`, replace ... with the package names found in the previous command.

Now you should be able to install virtualbox again.

Comment: Trying unistall the package virtualbox-5.0 I still  get the same error (VB is running..)